# compare non consecutive substrings in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-like

I have two comma separated strings:

- string1 = `abc,cde,efg`
- string2 = `abc,efg`

Is there any way that I can find intersection of the values i.e. any of the substrings in string1 that match the substrings in string2?

I have tried to split the string on the basis of a comma and find any string from the left side matches the substring of the right string then true else false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so like this:

```
SELECT s1.value
FROM STRING_SPLIT('abc,cde,efg', ',') AS s1
CROSS JOIN STRING_SPLIT('abc,efg', ',') AS s2
WHERE s1.value = s2.value

-- returns ('abc') and ('efg')
```

Comment: Thanks, man it helped me to build my logic and get the required output.